# Mixed Content - text and math

Tags: html, accessibility, screen-readers, wai-aria

I have some content on a page that represents math formulas. This content is inside a `<span>` but it has custom drawn content inside of it mixed with text. I have text description of the math content that I could put inside an `aria-label` attribute in the `<span>`, but screen readers seem to ignore aria attributes for non-form elements.

Is there a way to get screen readers to use an alternate description for the content inside a `<span>` or a `<div>`?

My html looks like this

```
<span aria-label='[TEXT DESCRIPTION]'>
    <svg>[SOME SVG CONTENT]</svg>
    <span>[SOME TEXT CONTENT]</span>
</span>
```

Comment: Does adding title attribute to SVG tag make any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code of

```
<span aria-label='[TEXT DESCRIPTION]'>
    <svg>[SOME SVG CONTENT]</svg>
    <span>[SOME TEXT CONTENT]</span>
</span>
```

looks slightly strange to me. The first thing I would do is change the outer span to a `<div>`. You may need to add something like `tabindex="-1"` to it. A more universal design approach would be to have the *[TEXT DESCRIPTION]* in plain text before/after *[SOME TEXT CONTENT]*, the idea is if a person with a visual impairment needs extra assistance, then other people may as well.

The other option could be like

```
<div>
  <svg aria-describedby="mathOne">.....</svg>
  <span id="mathOne" class="offScreen">{Description}</span>
  <span>Content</span>
</div>
```

From comments:

> visually the svg and text content may be overlayed or positioned absolutely so that it makes sense from a math formula perspective. Think sqrt symbol that grows with the radical and radix.

My point is not to do this. The *content `<span>`* should be enhancing things. Let's pretend I am displaying the quadratic formula, the code would look like

```
<div>
  <svg aria-describedby="mathOne">{Generated Formula}</svg>
  <span id="mathOne" class="offScreen">negative B plus or minus the 
   square root of the radical B squared - 4 a c end radical all over 2 a.</span>
  <span>In basic algebra, the quadratic formula is the solution of 
   the quadratic equation.</span>
</div>
```

Note: I haven't done stuff with math and visual impairments in 5 years, so there may be a better way of writing out the formula, but you get the idea.

Comment: This approach won't work exactly because visually the svg and text content may be overlayed or positioned absolutely so that it makes sense from a math formula perspective. Think sqrt symbol that grows with the radical and radix. 

I can't describe the individual parts separately, I need a description for the whole.

Comment: I've added an example

Comment: Probably a better answer than mine... Do screen readers read svg elements as graphics universally? If so then this achieves the effect I was going for but better.

Comment: I know there has been quite a bit of work in this area. This is one of those I don't actively follow due to personal interest mainly. Nothing comes immediately to mind regarding displaying text in a `<svg>`, but normally, if assistive technology knows how to interact with ARIA, they should just announce the `mathone` `<span>` and ignore the `<svg>`. OP *probably* could tack on  `role="presentation"` onto the `<svg>` if they want to make sure that the `<svg>` wasn't touched. Of course there's pros and cons to this

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the role attribute to something like img and set the aria-label, like so.

```
<span role="img" aria-label="This will appear like an image. Nothing will be read from inside, but you can set your own description">
<span>here is some non-screen-readerable stuff</span>
</span>
```

Is this what you're looking for?

p.s. non-screen-readerable may or may not be proper use of English. But I think it illustrates the point.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unforturenately this doesn't work. The screen reader still doesn't read the text. In fact it ignores the element altogether now.

Comment: I tried this with setting the role to textbox and it works. I'm not sure what side effects this could have but this may be a step in the right direction.

Comment: I'd advise against textbox, as that would be really confusing. what browser/screen reader configuration did you try img with? It works with FF and NVDA, but I didn't try all browsers with all screen readers.